# unable to copy a file from one git branch to another

Tags: git

I had tried to copy one file from a git branch to another with the suggested commands available

'git checkout otherbranch feature.dtsx'

online but it gives me an error "error:pathspec... did not match any known files to git"
any idea where am I going wrong.

Comment: Is `feature.dtsx` the full path of the file? If not, it should be `git checkout otherbranch full/path/to/feature.dtsx`. Also check that you *do* have this branch locally, it should be found with `git branch | grep otherbranch`

Comment: @RomainValeri,the dtsx file was inside a folder. could solve it. tks.